# How to capture a mouse over event for Windows Form Button

Tags: c++, winforms, uibutton, mouseevent, mouseover

Hi I am currently designing a simple UI using Windows Form, there's a few buttons here and there. I've been searching but cannot find how to catch a mouseover event for the button. Do you guys know any way to capture the mouseover event for the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MouseEnter`, `MouseHover` and/or `MouseLeave` event of the button control.

Read more at MSDN at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover.aspx